# Giving access to others on new GAE console

Tags: google-app-engine

With old GAE console you could invite others to join a project as owner or developer. Recently this option is moved to the new cloud console.
I used to use the old console to get access to client's so I can deploy application and make changes to it. The process involved with login into the project and inviting the new user. Then an email was sent to the new user and after he/she accepts the invite he/she could access this application directly from his/her console at appengine.google.com.

I tried the same process with the new changes couple of days ago, logged in into the new project and from the permission menu added myself to the project. However no email was sent to me and I still don't see this new application in my console!
Interestingly enough if I go to https://console.developers.google.com/project I see this new project there is no logs or data-objects listed. If I go to appengine.google.com I won't see this project and that's where I can go to application's console!

Not sure what's going on, has anyone seen this? Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Amir

Comment: It looks like everything you're doing is right.. remove and try to add yourself again. It seems that the invitation was lost somewhere or not sent.. Should be some technical issue.. if not resolved contact support.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so, I've removed and added again a few times and it's not working. I'll wait till Monday and then try to contact support. Any idea what's the best way? As per documentation the free support is here and they don't offer any email or phone support to users without a support plan.

Comment: Very strange.. did you try to add a different email?! Yes wait until Monday.. it might be fixed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue!
If you add a new project via appengine.google.com (old way) the application won't show up under Compute/App Engnie section of console.developers.google.com as simple as that.

The proper way to get all functionality is to add the new project using the console and then use the permission to add others.

It's strange and I couldn't find any documentation that explains it but I've tested and resolved my own issue this way. Hope this helps others.

Amir